# laravel-5.7: data is not saving into db

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

hi m trying to save data into db but it return only the next page without saving data into db, is there any solution to fix this problem,

controller:

```
  public function create(Request $request)
  {

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    $data = $request->all();
    $categories = new Categories;
    $categories->name = $data['category_name'];
    $categories_description = $data['description'];
    $categories->save();

       return view('admin.categories.index');
    }

    return view('admin.categories.create');
  }
```

blade file:

```
  <form class="k-form" method="post" action="{{ url('/admin/categories/index')}}" name="" id="k_form">@csrf
                <div class="row">

                                    <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Category Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="category_name" value="" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Description:</label>
                                    <div class="col-9">
                                        <textarea name="description" required="required"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-3 col-form-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-9">
                                        <div class="k-checkbox-single">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Add Category" style="background-color: #5867dd; color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px;" name="">
                                        </div>

            </form>
```

route:

```
  Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/admin/categories/create','CategoriesController@create');
```

Comment: can you post the model?

Comment: action="{{ url('/admin/categories/create')}}"

Comment: @aimme model is empty

Comment: model should have ```protected $guarded = [];`` can you check that?

Comment: @dparoli    Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Categories' not found, and error line is: $categories = new Categories;

Comment: import App\Categories. like this ```use App\Categories;```

Comment: Class 'App\Categories' not found

Comment: @aimme i hv write protected $guarded = []; in model but it says: Class 'App\Categories' not found

Comment: can you post complete files and their paths?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188659/discussion-between-programmer0001-and-aimme).

Answer (score 1):

You mistaken here

```
$categories_description = $data['description'];
```

It should be

```
$categories->description = $data['description'];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am not sure but try with another method name.

Comment: would u suggest any method

Comment: actually by default laravel take create method as returning of view and store method to store data in db.and could you put your table name in Model?

Comment: now i shift the controller into store method, but it still showing same result, should i hv to call the store method in route?

Comment: yes, You should call store method from route by post method.

Comment: this is route list how can i call store function in route?? https://ibb.co/rZ5M8HT

Comment: Try with this `Route::post('/admin/categories/create',['uses' => 'CategoriesController@store','as' => 'categories.store']);` and in blade `action = {{ route('categories.store') }}`

Comment: edit : Route::post('/admin/categories/store',['uses' => 'CategoriesController@store','as' => 'categories.store']); now??

Comment: 404
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Which page you are looking for?

Comment: can i send u complete code link here (extract file), if u can check it???

Comment: Ya sure,  I will check it

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in

```
 $categories = new Categories;
```

I believe it should be

```
$categories = new Category;
```

or

```
$category = new Category; //preferred
```

Model is singular where as table is plural as per laravel naming convention.

Further, add column names to fillable array if you are mass assigning the values. Like

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];
```

Also, make sure your model is in App folder and you have not created any sub directories such as 'App\Models' or something.

Comment: I am guessing that your form submit is not at all going to the right method. add dd($request->all()); right after if condition. Let me know the result.. Based on that I can help you.

Comment: Here is what you can do,
1. Name the route in web.php (Ex: categories.store)
2. Change the action in form like: action="{{ route('categories.store) }}"
3. In controller, move your saving code from create method to store method. Here you don't have to verify if the request is post.